# Error deleting resources while cleaning project & building J2me project

Tags: eclipse, java-me, lwuit, s60

I'm running Eclipse pulsar with S60 SDK for j2me development and using LWUIT.jar but I'm getting following error while cleaning my project

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Preverification Builder' on project 'YokeApp'.
Problems encountered while deleting resources.
Could not delete 'H:\Bitbucket\6-6-12 Yoke ME\yoke-j2me\.mtj.tmp\verified\libs\LWUIT_MIDP.jar'.
Problems encountered while deleting files.
Could not delete: H:\Bitbucket\6-6-12 Yoke ME\yoke-j2me\.mtj.tmp\verified\libs\LWUIT_MIDP.jar.
Problems encountered while deleting resources.
Could not delete 'H:\Bitbucket\6-6-12 Yoke ME\yoke-j2me\.mtj.tmp\verified\libs\LWUIT_MIDP.jar'.
Problems encountered while deleting files.
Could not delete: H:\Bitbucket\6-6-12 Yoke ME\yoke-j2me\.mtj.tmp\verified\libs\LWUIT_MIDP.jar.
```

I added LWUIT.jar to folder /lib/ which I created in my project.
I don't understand why I'm getting this error?

As initially Eclipse gets loaded and then I went to folder `mtj.tmp\verified\lib\LWUIT_MIDP.jar` and delete it. It's deleted successfully, but when I clean my project it created again then I run my project after that I am trying to clean my project by aborting it's competed execution but what??.. the same problem is back as mentioned above. Why this is happening and to solve it?

Comment: I also sometimes have this problem. Most of the times it is another  java process started from eclipse (by a plugin) which was not stopped correctly and still locks the jar files. You could kill these java processes (watch out not to kill eclipse).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to the specified path and delete the file manually. Refresh the project and try again, this must solve your problem.

Comment: it's not proper solution every time need to go and delete them.. :-(

Comment: This will not happen ever time. Sometimes while cleaning the project, the resources are not released properly, this stops them from being deleted, and hence the error. I faced this issue twice, though am working on the app for almost an year.

Comment: thanks for reply but it's not working in my case.

As initially eclipse gets loaded and then i went to folder mtj.tmp\verified\lib\LWUIT_MIDP.jar and delete it. ya.. it's deleted successfully, But when i clean my project it created again then i run my project after that i trying to clean my project by aborting it's competed execution but what??..  the same..problem as mention above can you please explain me why this is happening and to solve it..

Comment: I am experiencing this issue too. Manual deleting is NOT a good solution!

Comment: Key is "Could not delete ...", we must not delete manual anything, I had this trouble and I solved copying the missing directories and refreshing the proyect. The I could clean.